# Eclipse Scout client unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, junit, client, eclipse-scout

I am trying to create some unit test for scout client elements.

I have template for `AbstractGroupBox`, let say `AbstractMyBox`.

I see that I need to have `ScoutClientTestRunner` for this, so I create simple example :

```
@RunWith(ScoutClientTestRunner.class)
public class MyyBoxTemplateTest {

  AbstractMyBox box;

  @Before
  public void createTemplate() throws Exception {

    box = new AbstractMyBox() {};
  }


  @After
  public void destroyTemplate() throws Exception {

    box = null;
  }

  @Test
  public void testTitle() {

    String title = box.getLabel();
    assertEquals(title, TEXTS.get("Something"));
  }
}
```

When I run Unit test with `JUnit Plug-in test` it open new eclipse window

[image]

and clock is spinning, inside JUnit component it said `Runs: 0/0`

What am I doing wrong?

Marko

Comment: Just some comment about your code: in Java you do not need the 'destroyTemplate' method. Let the Garbage Collector do its job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have wrong run-configuration settings.

Under Run-Configuration / Main / Program to Run I need to set Run an Application : [No Application] - Headless Mode

Comment: or if you start your test/test suite with the appropriate set of plug-ins you do not have any application.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with Eclipse Scout. The following applies for every Eclipse bundle project (using Plug-in Development Environment (PDE) in your Eclipse IDE).

When your run a Test using “Run as > JUnit Plug-in Test”, all plug-ins in your workspace are started.

[image: Run as > JUnit Plug-in Test]

You can check this by opening the corresponding “Run Configuration”

[image: Run Configurations]

To reduce the set of started plug-ins, you should do the following:

1. Switch to “plug-ins selected bellow only”
2. Click on “Delesect All”
3. Select the Bundle where your test are located ('org.eclipsescout.demo.minifigcreator.client.test' in my case)
4. Click on “Add required Plug-ins”
5. [optional] click on “Validate Plug-ins” (expected message: “No problems were detected”)
6. Click on “Run”

[image: Run Configurations - correct set of plug-ins]

Your test should now run, and no second eclipse workbench should be opened.

Depending on your setup (workspace, team, source control...), it might be usefull to save this as launcher file and to share it with your team. (see the options in the “Commons” tab).

Comment: I try your way, but then tests are not ran. I have to set  [No Application] - Headless Mode and all plug-ins in order to be able to perform the tests